# Как прочесть значение из JSON на Java?

Tags: java, json

Как извлечь в переменную типа int число 2 из JSON-ответа на языке JAVA ? (вместо 2 может быть любое многозначное число)

> ```
> {
> "response": 2
> }
> ```

Без использования сторонних библиотек.

Comment: Без использования сторонних библиотек

Comment: В чем проблема с библиотеками?

Comment: @etki, у меня в программе это нужно всего один раз и в одном месте, зачем ради этого скачивать сторонние (дополнительные) библиотеки, если уже есть встроенные в AndroidStudio

Comment: туда же "встроен" градл, который делает все это скачивание за вас

Comment: @etki спасибо! Я пока начинающий и не знал этого. Я думал что если "сам дополнительно не скачал", то "это уже встроено")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Спасибо за ответы, нашел решение задачи:**

1. Импортируем библиотеки:

   ```
   import org.json.JSONException;
   import org.json.JSONObject;
   ```
2. В нужном месте пишем код:

   ```
   int myNumber;                
   try {
       myNumber = response.json.getInt("response");
   } catch (JSONException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   ```

   В итоге в переменной myNumber получаем наше число. 
   Импортированные библиотеки уже входят "в комплект" AndroidStudio, дополнительно их не надо скачивать.

Answer (score 2):

Ну можно так :)

```
String json = "{\"response\": 2}";
int number = Integer.valueOf(json.substring(13, 14));
```

Но почему бы не использовать GSON или Jackson?

Comment: Нужен более универсальный метод, т.к. вместо 2 может быть многозначное число: 1000, 100 000 и т.д.

Comment: у меня в программе это нужно всего один раз и в одном месте, зачем ради этого скачивать сторонние (дополнительные) библиотеки, если уже есть встроенные в AndroidStudio

Answer (score 1):

Можно например использовать регулярки, но тоже выходит не очень универсально.
Если структура ответа будет отличаться, придётся руками вырезать лишнее.

Пример:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> tmp = new ArrayList<>();
    tmp.add("{\"response\": 2}");
    tmp.add("{\"response\": 0}");
    tmp.add("{\"response\": null}");
    tmp.add("{\"response\": 11}");
    tmp.add("{\"response\": 111}");
    tmp.add("{\"response\": 1111}");
    tmp.add("{\"response\": 11111}");
    tmp.add("{\"response\": -1111111}");

    tmp.forEach(a -> {
        System.out.println(parseJsonInt(a));
    });
}

public static Integer parseJsonInt(String json) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(json);
    while (m.find()) {
        return Integer.valueOf(m.group());
    }
    return null;
}
```